# What is wrong with this RegEx statement?

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie_STAGE=GfXs7fdNQwNCgkgpCcRoDWrihrVb/eX/et1JM24qlV01799kLyjGeKjbxVIeMTQA; domain=.stage.test.com; path=/
```

I created the following RegEx to extract the AuthVerifyCookie, but I don't know what the full name will be (AuthVerifyCookie_STAGE; AuthVerifyCookie_INT, etc.):

```
Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie.*=(.+?);
```

Instead of extracting: `GfXs7fdNQwNCgkgpCcRoDWrihrVb/eX/et1JM24qlV01799kLyjGeKjbxVIeMTQA`

I get: `.stage.test.com`

This is Javascript regex being used in JMeter. I'm testing the Regex here: https://regex101.com/r/ICvU1m/1

Why is it not recognizing the first match?

Comment: You get the value of the first capturing group. What is your expected match? https://regex101.com/r/r6cK9q/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't understand your response. Shouldn't this be extracting the value of `AuthVerifyCookie`, not the value of `domain`.

Comment: Put a full URL to your case in 101.

Comment: @Appleoddity No the `.*` will match until the end of the string, and will then backtrack until the last occurrence of `=` Then it tries to match as least as possible until the first `;`,You could do it like this https://regex101.com/r/r6cK9q/2

Comment: @PM77-1 Edited and added.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ICvU1m/2

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, that appears to work and I understand it. But, do you care to explain why my version does not work in an answer?

Comment: As mentioned, the `*` is a greedy quantifier. Just adding a `?` to make it lazy would work too: `Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie.*?=(.+?);`. A greedy regex tries to match as much of the string as possible. It scans until the last `=` instead of stopping at the first `=`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you tried contains `.*` which will match until the end of the string because it is greedy. Then it will try to match an `=` and will backtrack giving back as least as possible so it will match the last `=`

This part `(.+?);` will then capture in a group 1+ chars except a newline non greedy (as least as possible) and then match a `;` which will give `.stage.test.com` in the first capturing group.

What you could do is either make the first quantifier non greedy `.*?=` or use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any char except an `=` in the first part, and also use a negated character class to match any char except a `;` in the second part.

```
Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie[^;]*=([^;]+);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QDfgO3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches these parts of the input:

`Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie` matches `Set-Cookie: AuthVerifyCookie`

`.*` matches `_STAGE=GfXs7fdNQwNCgkgpCcRoDWrihrVb/eX/et1JM24qlV01799kLyjGeKjbxVIeMTQA; domain`

`=` matches `=`

`(.*?)` matches `.stage.test.com`

`;` matches `;`

`path=/` is not matched.

Informally, the rule for `*` is that it should match the longest substring it can, provided that the rest of the regex is matched. The substring that ends at the third `=` does not leave enough of the input for the rest of the regex to match. The second `=` **does** leave enough input for the rest of the regex to match. The first `=` also would leave enough input, but the second `=` allows the match for the first`.*` to be longer, so that is what is chosen.

You could replace the first `.*` by `[^=]*` to prevent matching a string in which the first `=` is embedded, or `.*?` to match the shortest possible substring rather than the longest one.